# Зачем при скачивании шрифтов с ними поставляются также жирные и наклонные их вариации?

Tags: html, шрифты, google-fonts

При скачивании шрифта X, например, с Google Fonts со шрифтом X в архиве обычно находятся X-bold и X-italic. Зачем нужны эти шрифты, если использование в коде `<b></b>`, `<i></i>` или `<strong></strong>`, `<em></em>` прекрасно выполняет свою задачу?

Или все-таки нужно вручную переписывать стили элементов вроде этого?

```
b {
    font-family: "X-bold";
    font-style: bold;
}
```

Comment: А Вы попробуйте не подключать жирный шрифт и увидите как справится <b>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Над созданием большинства шрифтов работают специально обученные люди, это очень трудоемкая и кропотливая работа. Каждый вензель на букве не случаен, а продуман.
Потому и каждое начертание шрифта (курсивное, жирное, полужирное...) тоже тщательно спланировано дизайнером.

Браузеры могут самостоятельно имитировать различные начертания, но они (возможно, незначительно для некоторых шрифтов, но иногда разительно) будут отличаться от задуманного разработчиком. Особенно хорошо это видно на крупных символах. Ибо при разработке шрифта буквы прорабатываются индивидуально дизайнером, а браузер изменяет начертание общим универсальным алгоритмом.

Comment: В дополнение, с примерами: http://css-live.ru/articles/skazhem-net-lozhnomu-zhirnomu.html

Comment: В итоге нужно стилизовать теги `b`, `i` и подобные вручную?

Comment: @smellyshovel в случае наличия необходимых начертаний, можно прописывать, например, так: `p {font-famliy: Roboto; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal}` 
`strong {font-family: Roboto Bold; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal}` 
`em {font-family: Roboto Bold; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic}`